# Unable to load python flask API with a docker container

Tags: python, api, docker, flask

I'm trying to learn Docker containers with APIs. I have created a simple Hello World python REST API with flask:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", debug=True, port=8080)
```

This works when I run the script and go to http://localhost:8080/

This is my Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:2.7-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /hello_world

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /hello_world

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8080

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "hello_world.py"]
```

requirements.txt:

```
Flask
```

My current directory contains Dockerfile, hello_world.py and requirements.txt.

I can successfully build the image with `docker build -t hello_world ."`
Running it with `docker run -p 8080:8080 -t hello_world` gives me the following output:

```
 Serving Flask app "hello_world" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
 WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
 Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 985-433-141
```

When I try going to http://127.0.0.1:8080/ I get the "Can't reach this page" error. Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Try running the app on 0.0.0.0 and see if that helps. I know that would make a difference if you were working between two machines, but I'm not sure if it works on containers

Comment: And please read the WARNING carefully!

Comment: So dumb question... where are you typing 127.0.0.1?  Because if it isn't in the actual docker instance you will be hitting the wrong IP.  Instead have you tried typing the IP address of the docker vm itself?

Comment: so Rking14, did that help?

Comment: @Ben has the correct answer. `0.0.0.0` will work but `127.0.0.1` won't when you containerize the Flask app. `127.0.0.1` is the container's loopback not the host's. Alternatively, you can run the container with `--net=host` and retain the `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @Ben Yes, the app worked on 0.0.0.0:8080. Thank you. I initially built a REST API in Java with Springboot and placed it in a Docker container which worked on 127.0.0.1. However, when I tried making the REST API in python with Flask, I was confused why 127.0.0.1 didn't work.

Comment: @Rking14 cool then